# Monero Wallet For Raspberry Pi 1? (ARMv6 I think)

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, compile, raspberry-pi

Is there a version of the monero wallet for the Raspberry Pi Model B that is up to date? I have looked and can only find ones a year or older often with the links 404ing. Or could anyone help me compile one? (specifically the wallet I plan to use a remote node)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As seen on the Monero downloads page, there are no official builds for ARM v6. There are only v7/v8: https://github.com/monero-project/monero/releases

However, Howard Chu has some unofficial builds listed here that include ARM v6: https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/543euo/monero_unofficial_arm_builds/

FYI, these may not work with the current network, especially after the next hard fork when RingCT will be enforced network wide (Sept 2017).

**Edit:** Hyc released some new binaries! (v0.10.3.1): https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/6eg72k/updated_binaries_for_armv6_raspberry_pi_1/

Comment: Thanks, however I found this link too when searching and the link for the raspberry pi 1 and zero gives a 404 error. Any idea how I may go about compiling my own? As instructions I found were outdated.

Comment: I had some problems with my ARMv6 build environment that I only sorted out recently. Can upload new binaries if needed.

Comment: If you're building on the Pi itself there should be no special steps required, just type "make". Assuming you have the prereqs already installed. Of course it will take a very long time to complete, and you'll need around 3GB of swap space. Meanwhile, I've posted a new build: https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/6eg72k/updated_binaries_for_armv6_raspberry_pi_1/

Had to delete the old builds because I was running out of disk space on my server.

Comment: I am trying to compile on RaPi too (ARMv6). **make** outputs loads of errors (unknown type names/endianness/...) and then quits among the lines of `make[3]: *** [external/db_drivers/liblmdb/CMakeFiles/lmdb.dir/build.make:63: external/db_drivers/liblmdb/CMakeFiles/lmdb.dir/mdb.c.o] Error 1`. What may be the reason? (Same issue regardless if using sources at todays latest commit or at tags/v0.10.3.1)

Answer (score 3):

Reddit User [/u/hyc_symas](https://www.reddit.com/user/hyc_symas),
kindly compiled some new binaries for me they can be found here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/6eg72k/updated_binaries_for_armv6_raspberry_pi_1/

Answer (score 1):

Goto monero forum and search for bitmonerod-node-on-rpi2-working.  The source downloaded from git for monero-project/monero should support armv6 builds